# How to complete circuit diagram?

Tags: wiring, diagram, drawing

I have limited knowledge on electrics and wanted to ask how I can complete this circuit, how would I go about wiring it up?

1. Bulb should ONLY be ON when Input A is ON and Input B is OFF.
2. Bulb should turn OFF whenever Input B is ON or when both Inputs are OFF or when both Inputs are ON.
3. Input A is always ON when Input B is ON.

Is there any semiconductor or electrical device I need for it? If someone can redraw diagram including if there is anything else to add like ground wire to make this work I would appreciate it a lot.

[image: Incomplete circuit]

Comment: It's likely that the ignition switch is wired to something else and without knowing precisely what it is wired to it's difficult to advise. If you said I want the bulb to be on only when input A = 1 and input B = 0 and off whenever input B is 1 then this is easier but it's complicated by your reality and this raises other questions.

Comment: hi thanks I have re-drawn diagram does it make much sense now?

Comment: I can't see the schematic...

Comment: I don't see a schematic either.  Also, your points 2 and 3 are redundant noise to point 1.  You clearly want the function A and (not B).

Answer (score 2):

You want the logical function:

BULB = A and (not B)

This can be realized directly with a inverter and a AND gate if all the signals are positive logic.  This equation can also be re-written to use different blocks and for different polarity of the inputs and/or output.  For example, the above is equal to:

BULB = (not A) nor B

Such simple logic can be implemented with just a couple of transistors when speed isn't critical.  For example:

[image]

For the light to turn on, transistor Q2 must be on. This can only happen when A is high to supply its base current.  However, when B is high, the base of Q2 will always be low regardless of what A is doing.

### Added in response to misguided comments

The OP's point number 3 is telling us what the inputs do, not what the circuit must do in response.  It is really telling us that one line in the truth table isn't used.  Point 1 tells us the whole truth table.  My circuit above works correctly for all possible combinations of inputs, so the fact that one of the four possible input states never occurs doesn't matter.

From the OP's point 1, the truth table is:

```
      A     B   OUT
    ---   ---   ---
1:    0     0     0
2:    0     1     0
3:    1     0     1
4:    1     1     0
```

Point 3 only states that line 2 never occurs.  Again, this does not matter to my circuit since it implements the full truth table.  Another way of saying this is that we could show the OUT value for line 2 as "don't care".

As for the comment that I need to show the "switch wiring", that makes even less sense.  The OP never referred to any switches, so it make no sense that I need to show any.  My circuit does use transistors are switches, but these are already clearly shown, and there is a explanation below the diagram on how the circuit works.

### Response to more confused comments

The OP's point 3 says *"Input A is always ON when Input B is ON"*.  This is a statement of what is, not a description of some action the circuit must perform.  This simple statement is being consistantly misinterpreted as the rule: *"he specified that input A must be ON whenever input B is ON"*.  The error in interpretation is that this is being taken as a rule that the circuit must somehow turn on A when B is on.  This is simply not what the OP's original statement means.  Note that A and B are **inputs**.  By definition, we don't control inputs.  Since there are 2 inputs and each can have one of two states, there are only a total of 4 possible input conditions.  Since the number is small, it is easy to deal with them by exhaustion, such as by using the truth table shown.

This is like writing a specification for a solar panel installation and saying that the sun is always south of vertical at noon.  This is only meant as additional information, not as a requirement that the sun be rearranged to force it south at noon.

The OP's point 3 is like the sun at noon.  It is giving us additional information, which is that when input B is on, we will always find input A also on.  The specification of what the circuit needs to do is spelled out clearly in point 1: *"Bulb should ONLY be ON when Input A is ON and Input B is OFF"*.  This tells us that in the case of A off and B on, the output should be off.  Point 3 is giving us the additional information that this case will never occur.  It would therefore be legitimate for the circuit to have undetermined output or have the output on in the case of A off and B on.  The circuit I showed above happens to produce the desired output in that case anyway.  That is not necessary, but it also does no harm.

Comment: Your circuit doesn't fulfill condition 3: "3) Input A is always ON when Input B is ON."

Comment: You need to show the switch wiring for your schematic to make sense.

Comment: @EMFi: Wrong.  See addition to my answer.

Comment: @What: Your comment makes no sense.  See addition to my answer.

Comment: @Olin: The OP clearly stated that: "Input A is ALWAYS on if input B is ON"...   It's just as clear that your circuit **can't** satisfy those requirements, so how is my comment wrong?

Comment: @Olin: The OP showed a switch on his sketch which is closed when the device on the right is in the Switched off state and open when the device on the right is in the Switched on state.

Comment: @Olin: Your truth table is flawed in that it doesn't reflect the OP's requirement for A always to be on when B is on. Hint: your truth table needs another column or two on the input side.

Comment: @EMFi: First A always being on when B is on is not a requirement, it's a condition, so nothing for the circuit to "satisfy".  There are 2 inputs, each with 2 possible states, for a maximum possible combination of 4 inputs.  My truth table therefore shows all of them.  The extra condition only tells us that line 2 never occurs.  Show me a input condition that does not result in the light being on/off correctly.  In case the line 2 condition does occur, this circuit will keep the light off.

Comment: The issue isn't semantic so, whatever you choose to call what the OP asked for, the fact remains that he specified that input A must be ON whenever input B is ON and, in the end, neither your circuit nor your truth table provide for that functionality, so they are flawed.

Comment: @EMFi: I'm not sure now whether you're being dense, deliberately contrary, or just trolling.  In any case, I added to my answer to address this one last time.  I am now done with this.  Don't expect any additional response.

Comment: Ah, I see... you're so dead set on not having to admit to a simple error that after a protracted "argument" you can't possibly win, you take one last parting shot and run away.  That's OK; I'm sure we'll cross paths again.

Answer (score 1):

S1 and S2 are switches, and K1 is a DPDT relay shown in the de-energized position.

When S1 is made, "A" goes hot (ON) and when S2 is made, B goes hot, energizing the relay.

Under condition 1:

> 1) Bulb should ONLY be ON when Input A is ON and Input B is OFF

S1 will be made and S2 will not, providing a path for current through S1, the lamp, and the normally closed contacts of K1, lighting the lamp.

Under condition 2:

> 2) Bulb should turn OFF whenever Input B is ON or when both Inputs are
>   OFF or when both Inputs are ON.

When S2 is made and and "B" is ON, K1 will be energized and its normally closed (NC) contacts will be opened, turning the lamp OFF by disconnecting it from the battery regardless of whether S1 is made or not.

When both inputs are OFF, S1 will disconnect the lamp from the battery, turning it OFF, and when they're both ON, the opened NC contacts of K1 will turn the lamp OFF by disconnecting it from the battery

Under condition 3:

> 3) Input A is always ON when Input B is ON.

K1 will be energized by S2 and the battery will be connected to "A" through K1's now closed NO contacts, but the battery will be disconnected By the opened NC contacts, so the lamp won't light.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic makes no sense, in part because there is no ground or any other way to know which node the A and B voltages are with respect to.  It is therefore impossible to tell what currents will flow where when A and B are at high and low voltages.  Remember, a voltage is always *between two points*.  When a ground is shown, we can assume voltages are implicitly relative to it, but that is missing in your schematic.

Comment: I'm sorry the schematic makes no sense to you, since it's just simple relay logic which I used to satisfy the OP's requirements.  As far as a hard 'ground' goes, there's really no need for one since the entire circuit floats and the voltage between any two points can be measured using either point as a reference.  For simplicity's sake, though, and to make the circuit less confusing, one might choose the battery negative to be the common reference and even elect to draw in a ground signal to reflect that, but it really makes no difference as far as the operation of the circuit goes.

Comment: No, some kind of reference is needed for the A and B signals.  You have them entering your schematic at single points.  Put another way, you can think of A and B as being voltage sources, which have two connections.  You show where the positive connection goes, but don't show us where to connect the negative output of each voltage source.

Comment: Since the OP didn't provide any details as to what's connected to A and B, - it could be a single resistor connected between them, for instance - or anything else about what he didn't show, it seems pointless to argue on endlessly about unverifiable minutiae.  What concerns me more, though, is your use of veiled abuse in what is purported to be a "scholarly" venue.  An example would be your use of "**Added in response to misguided comments**" - in attention-getting **bold**, no less - earlier on, in what would seem to be an attempt to discredit those who disagree with you. How say you?